# Jasmin ByteCode Storing a String

Tags: string, jvm-bytecode, jasmin

I am trying to store a String in Jasmin Bytecode. After allot of research I could not find if this was possible and if it was, how it should be done. I could only find out how I could print it out(this is how I print a string).
I also thought of storing a string as an array of chars, but thought there should be an easier way.

```
.class public HelloWorld
.super java/lang/Object

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  .limit stack 3
  .limit locals 1

  getstatic      java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  ldc            "Hello World."
  invokevirtual  java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V

  return

.end method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer:
A string is not a primitive datatype so you save it/load it with:

```
aastore (number)
aaload (number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Saw your answer, now I am not sure what the question was.

Anyway, this works for me:

```
.class public HelloWorld
.super java/lang/Object

.field static private message Ljava/lang/String;

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  .limit stack 1
  .limit locals 1

  ldc            "Hello World."
  putstatic      HelloWorld/message Ljava/lang/String;
  invokestatic   HelloWorld/print()V
  return
.end method

.method public static print()V
  .limit stack 2
  .limit locals 2
  getstatic      java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  getstatic      HelloWorld/message Ljava/lang/String;
  invokevirtual  java/io/PrintStream/println(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  return
.end method
```

Everything is static, which is not nice, but `main` sets `message` to "Hello World.", and invokes `print`. Then `print` gets `message` and prints it with the `System.out.println` call, stolen from your original code.

While I would love to be the magical being who reads those two pages of jasmin documentation and knows everything, but in the process actually I also digged out that JDK comes with a decompiler (JDK/bin/javap), and it produces 'disassembly' if you invoke it with `-c` switch. Somehow `invokevirtual` just did not want to work on the static method...

Comment: What I meant was this:
If I make a String and want to reference it later, how do I store(save) it.